# Uncaught error: There are multiple templates named 'velvet'. Each template needs a unique name. (..)

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have recently deployed my meteor app ( www[.]webmill[.]eu ) which was working just fine locally. I dealt with MIME type errors but am stuck with this one:

```
Error: There are multiple templates named 'velvet'. Each template needs a unique name. 1b1a247fc034d5089f331ec9540138ff6afd5f39.js:75:306
```

I checked but I don't have any duplicates and I can't find any info on how to solve this apart from a similar issue that existed with a meteor package, accounts-ui-bootstrap-3.
 On desktop, I only get the initial full background image without being able to navigate anywhere on the page. Also I can put anything in my url like so : webmill.eu/nowaythisisarealurl and it will still display the same thing. It works as intended on displays under 1070 px width.

meteor packages I'm using:
meteor-platform
mizzao:bootstrap-3
pfafman:font-awesome-4

Any suggestions/help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have your code available in a public repository to examine?  Have you looked at the contents of  1b1a247fc034d5089f331ec9540138ff6afd5f39.js?

Comment: Yes, I have but didn't make much sense of it. I've found you on bitbucket and shared my repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two templates named velvet.  I cloned your repo and ran this:

```
grep -r -i 'name="velvet"' *
```

Result:

```
app/client/image.html:<template name="velvet">
app/client/index.html:<template name="velvet">
```

Change the name of one of the templates.